Deformation of Breather by Isometric Mapping
Is it  possible to isometrically map the  Breather surface $ (K=-1) $ so that the end points at infinity on  z-axis $(z=-\infty, z=+\infty)$ map onto to two finite separation points $( z=+a, z=-a) $ on the z-axis of symmetry with an axial  displacement/ compression ?
Mathematica Code copied from internet and an image :

p = 0.498888; vmax =47.1232; q = Sqrt[1 - p^2];
Breather[u_, v_] := 
  Module[{d = p ((q Cosh[p u])^2 + (p Sin[q v])^2)}, 
   x = -u + 2 q^2 Cosh[p u] Sinh[p u]/d;
   y = 2 q Cosh[p u] (-q Cos[v] Cos[q v] - Sin[v] Sin[q v])/d;
   z = 2 q Cosh[p u] (-q Sin[v] Cos[q v] + Cos[v] Sin[q v])/d; {x, y, 
    z}];
ParametricPlot3D[Breather[u, v], {u, -8, 8}, {v, 0, vmax}, 
 Mesh -> {59, 123}]


If we have $a=0,$ then we have ribbed Lemniscate meridians ridges of the surface containing only "umbilicals" on the axis of symmetry at one point.
For $a>0$ "umbilicals" form  on two points on the z-axis of symmetry forming a full canopy shape whose segments look somewhat similar to a shop Sun Shade or a Baby Perambulator.

Could we tweak the code somehow? All suggestions welcome.

You may reduce the parameter boundaries
SetOptions[ParametricPlot3D, Mesh -> {12, 12}, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][0.5 + #3/2] &), 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, ImageSize -> 100];

Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Breather[u, v], {u, umin, umax}, {v, 0, vmax},
  ViewPoint -> 
   5 {Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]],  
     Sin[\[Theta]]}  ],
 {{umin, -2}, -10, 0},
 {{umax, 2}, 0, 10},
 {{\[Phi], -1}, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {{\[Theta], 1}, 0, \[Pi]}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]


